# What does this line (cap>> frame;) mean in the source code?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I am learning OpenCV library with C++ and got stuck in this line of code "cap >> frame;"

```
cv::Mat frame;
while(1)
{
       cap>> frame; // <= What does this line do in the program 
       if(!frame.data)break;
       cv::imshow("Input", frame);
       if(cv::waitKey(33)>= 0) break;
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: `cap` is probably an istream operator, fetching input

Answer (score 0):

This line of code take new frame from camera

```
cap>> frame;
```